# Does fgets() hold somehow where it stopped reading from a FILE *?

Tags: c, shell, file, unix

I am trying to get a sample (shell script) program on how to write to a file:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char buff[1024];
  size_t len, idx;
  ssize_t wcnt;
  for (;;){
    if (fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin) == NULL)
      return 0;
    idx = 0;
    len = strlen(buff);
    do {
      wcnt = write(1,buff + idx, len - idx);
      if (wcnt == -1){ /* error */
        perror("write");
        return 1;
      }
      idx += wcnt;
    } while (idx < len);
  }
}
```

So my problem is this: Let's say I want to write a file of 20000 bytes so every time I can only write (at most) 1024 (buffer size).
Let's say that in my first attempt everything is going perfect and fgets() reads 1024 bytes and in my first do while I write 1024 bytes.
Then, since we wrote "len" bytes we exit the do-while loop.
**So now what??** The buffer is full from our previous reading.   **It seems to me that for some reason it is implied that fgets() will now continue reading from the point it reached in in-file the last time.** (buf[1024] here).
**How come, fgets() knows where it stopped reading in the in-file?**
I checked the man page :

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored in the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.
> fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when the end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*

So from that, I get that it returns a pointer to the first element of buf, which is always buf[0],
that's why I am confused.

Comment: *How come, fgets() knows where it stopped reading in the in-file*. That info is stored inside the file stream structure (`stdin` in this case). But it also sounds you may be confused about how that relates to `buff` - it doesn't as `fgets` just writes to the start of `buf` every time it is called and it always returns either `buf` or `NULL`.

Comment: Yeah, you're confusing the buffer that `fgets` hands you with the stream in the FILE object you hand to `fgets`.

Comment: @kaylum I thought FILE * ostream points to the first char of the file. If I got it right you suggest that stdin is "moving" ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you elaborate a little bit more on how FILE  object behaves here?

Comment: It contains a "stream," so the stream remembers where it left off.

Comment: `FILE *` is just the implementation's internal representation of the state of the stream (ie, usually a pointer to a `struct`). One of the fields in the struct will be the file position which is updated every time the calling code does a read or write.

Comment: "FILE * ostream points to the first char of the file." --> No.  `ostream` points to a structure with various data organized in some fashion.  It contents are not meant for user reading.

Comment: As others pointed out, you've confused C run-time file system buffers, with your own input buffer. The details are implementation defined, but for terminal devices (ie; stdin), there's usually an asynchronous process that's collecting input at the OS level, then when your code calls into `fgets`, it drains that OS buffer, up to the EOL, via an API call and writes it to the buffer that you supplied.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think that;s okay actually. Imagine if , for some reason write() did not achieve to write 1024 bytes (no error    ) , we will remain in the do- while loop. SO we want to continue from where we where left in the buffer in order to avoid recopying..

Comment: @brucebanner Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a`FILE` stream, it contains information about the position in the file (among other things). `fgets` and other functions like `fread`or `fwrite` merely utilize this information and updates it when an operation is performed.
So, whenever `fgets` reads from the stream, the stream will be updated to maintain the position, so that the next operation starts off where the previous ended.